# How can I pass an image with array in vue axios post?

Tags: vue.js, axios

1. Here I push the data of the form into an array with image.

```
this.tableData.push({
  sub_group: this.items.subGroup,
  amount: this.items.amount,
  item_name: this.items.item_name,
  quantity: this.items.quantity,
  category: this.items.category,
  name: this.items.name,
  image: this.items.image,
});
```

2. In the below code I am passing the array of data(`this.tableData`) which consists of image too but when I stringify it I get only the path empty. If I dont stringyfy it I get the result as [object object]. How can I resolve it?

```
submitForm(formName) {
  let formdata= new FormData();
  formdata.append('value[]',JSON.stringify(this.tableData));
  console.log(this.tableData);
  axios.post('/api/save-menu', formdata, {
      headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  }).then(response => {
      this.$notify({
          title: 'Success',
          message: response.data.message,
          type: 'success'
      });
  });
}
```

3. After `Json.stringify` in server-side I get data as

```
"value" => array:1 [
    0 => "[{"sub_group":1,"amount":"Bert Crosby","item_name":"Brody York","quantity":"Belle Jordan","category":"Corporis sequi bland","name":"Cheryl Dunlap","image":{"$path":""}}]"
  ]
```

4. Without `Json.Stringify` I get the data as

```
"value" => array:1 [
  0 => "[object Object]"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [object-to-formdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata) npm module to create the right FormData for transfer. You can't use JSON.stringify because JSON doesn't have File type and your file was lost. [Here is a link about types that you can transfer with JSON](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-data-types/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Use correct type in your form. `<input type="file">`

Then you have multiple ways to fetch the image. (FormData Object or File Object).

**As FormData:**

```js
let form = new FormData();
  files.forEach(file => {
    form.append(file.name, file);
  });
axios.post(url, form);
```

You can send as **File Object** (Blob).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

```js
const imageFile = File("your-image.ext");
axios.post(url, imageFile, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': imageFile.type
  }
});
```

Comment: Here i was passing an array of data so I can't append the file only on formdata , i need to pass the file inside arrays. Is there any way to do that?? Pass the image inside array?

Comment: @ajitsubedi For setting data to your FormData Object you can use the `set()` FormData method. Like `yourFormDataObj.set('myImage', image.value);`